# Xamarin Forms - What is the current device/system type?

Tags: xamarin, uwp, system-information

I was working by debug my app with a `Microsoft Phone 10` when I realized **"UWP is a cross windows logic"**, so now I'm working with my computer.

However, a question comes up in my mind :

**How can you know/get information about what type of system your app is running on?**

I mean by this question, by example, does my app is currently running on a phone or on a computer?

Thank for your help !

Comment: Please stop posting the tags in your question title, that's duplicate info.

Comment: Thank to tell me this, I though it was for different things :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PCL or SAP

The static Device class includes several properties and methods that allow your code to deal with device differences at run time in a very simple and straightforward manner:

- The Device.OS property returns a member of the TargetPlatform
  enumeration: iOS,  Android, WinPhone, or Other. The WinPhone member
  refers to all the Windows and Windows Phone platforms.
- The Device.Idiom property returns a member of the TargetIdiom
  enumeration: Phone, Tablet, Desktop, or Unsupported.

You can use these two properties in if and else statements, or a switch and case block, to execute code specific to a particular platform.

[Device](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.Device/)

Comment: Thank ! :) Does it works for Xbox app? If yes, how does work the Debug part? :)

Comment: I think yes is compatible try 

if( Device.Idiom == "Unsupported"){
   
}

verify if enter

Comment: Check this page https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xbox-apps/index?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: I was thinking, `idiom` works for each platform, not only **UWP** ?

Comment: idiom work for identify devices. Phone, Tablet, Desktop, or Unsupported.